# smart way to multiply two lists to make a python dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have two lists of data, which is:

```
 a = [1,1,1, 0,0,0]
 b = [9,8,7, 6,5,4]
```

and my desired output is:

```
df = [[9,9,9, 0,0,0],
       [8,8,8, 0,0,0],
       [7,7,7, 0,0,0],
       [6,6,6, 0,0,0],
       [5,5,5, 0,0,0],
       [4,4,4, 0,0,0]]
```

What I'm currently doing is something like:

```
for aa in a:

    counter = 0

    df = pd.DataFrame()

    while counter<len(b): 

        df[counter] = pd.Series(b)*a[counter]

        counter+=1
```

which seems, definitely inefficient.

In my real application, the size of a and b is very large, so efficiency issue rises.

Any smart efficient way to solve this problem? Any suggestion would be appreciated

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try `numpy.matmul` with `a` and inverse of `b`?

Comment: Will the original size of 'a' and 'b' look similar to the example you provided?

Comment: @bunbun I haven't tried that I will give that a shot too

Comment: @Marmik Shah actually, it would be quite different

Comment: @H.Choi Ah! The answer provided is good. But usually when you want to build a matrix, the complexity will be O(row * column) in majority of the cases. It is because you are creating row * column values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the outer product `np.outer` and initialize a pandas dataframe with the result:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = [1,1,1, 0,0,0]
b = [9,8,7, 6,5,4]

pd.DataFrame(np.outer(b, a))

   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  9  9  9  0  0  0
1  8  8  8  0  0  0
2  7  7  7  0  0  0
3  6  6  6  0  0  0
4  5  5  5  0  0  0
5  4  4  4  0  0  0
```

Comment: Wow! thank you very much! elegant and efficient answer :)